# How to hide 3D viewport settings

Tags: 3d-view, interface

Is there a way to hide these 3D viewport settings? I use this small panel as a preview for the camera, but it is obscured by settings that I don't need here.

[image: Viewport obscured by settings]

Comment: Hello :). *View > Sidebar (N)*

Comment: @JachymMichal Awesome, thank you!

Comment: if you wanna have even more space: uncheck show header   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNGMP.png